# Github deploying issues

Tags: reactjs, git, github, deployment

When I try to use `npm run deploy` on github, it throws me the following errors:

```
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/main
error: github.com:Aris-Empanta/Accountant_landing_page.git did not send all necessary objects

Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/main
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/main
fatal: failed to run repack
error: task 'gc' failed
```

Any suggestions?

---

Though VS code command line, everytime I change my project I push the changes you know, git add, git commit, git push origin. After that when I confirm the merging from github, I write npm run deploy to deploy the changed project to gh-pages. It was working, but suddenly stopped.

Comment: Are you talking about using `npm run deploy` in a GitHub CI action? Tell us more about your setup.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.